# Cypress indentifies element but clicks beside the element

Tags: cypress

I try to click a Button in a Modal Dialog.

The html Looks the following:

```
<div slot="buttons" class="modal-footer au-target" au-target-id="92"> 
    <button class="btn btn-primary au-target" 
        id="buttonNein" 
        name="buttonNein" 
        click.delegate="clickedNein()" 
        au-target-id="352">Cancel</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary au-target" 
        id="buttonJa" 
        name="buttonJa" 
        click.delegate="clickedJa()" 
        data-backdrop="false" 
        disabled.bind="isJaDisabled"
        au-target-id="354">Delete</button>
    <!--slot--> 
</div>
```

It takes the Modal some time to Display, so i heve to wait for it to be visible.
The test Code Looks the following:

```
cy.get('#buttonJa').should('be.visible').click();
```

Now Cypress seems to identify the right button, as it is highlighted in the TestRunner, but Cypress is not Clicking it, in the TestRunner, it is displayed as if Cypress clicked above the button.
I took a screenshot to illustrate the error:

[illustrates the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRAoI.png)

I tired to run the Test in the Chrome browser and in the Electron Version, both failed with the same result. I also played with the Viewport Resolution, it showed no effect.

Thank you in advance

Comment: have you tried cy.get('#buttonJa').should('be.visible').click({force:true});

Comment: yeah, i already tried that, there is also no error message shown, it looks like the Click worked fine, but it didn't...

Comment: what about  cy.get('#buttonJa').trigger('mousedown')

Comment: just tried that, gives me the same result. I am not sure if the hint that cypress clicked above is correct... it just seems to not display the click position correctly as the position changes when i scroll in the DOM snapshots... Still it misses the button, with click, trigger('mousedown') or trigger('click')... maybe i just wait for it to be visible and execute some javascript to click it

Comment: if you add a `cy.wait(1000)` before the click does it work? It may be the framework has not yet registered the event listeners at the time of the click

Comment: Yeah, this works^^. great thank you so much.

Comment: have you solved this more consistenly ?